# How to distribute integers topdown a set of persons?

Tags: java, algorithm

I have a sorted set of persons, and I want to distribute a defined count topdown.
Example:

Scenario:

```
int i = 8;
personA = 0;
personB = 0;
personC = 0;
```

Desired result:

```
personA = 3;
personB = 3;
personC = 2;
```

Of course I could iterate with for/while loops, but if `i` is very large that might be inefficient.

Can the result also be optained by devision, without loops?

Pseudocode:

```
distributed = 0;
while (distributed < i) {
    for (int p : persons) {
        p++;
        distributed++;
    }
}
```

interation steps:

```
1-1-1 > start over > 2-2-2 > start over > 3-3-2
```

Comment: What if i = 10, how will you distrubute? 4-4-2 or 4-3-3

Comment: Always from top to bottom: 4-3-3

Comment: If it is top to bottom why not 4-4-2(second higher than third) or 5-3-2 or 6-3-1

Comment: I want to achieve the same result that I would get using the loop (updated above), but without acually having to loop, because if I get like `10000000` looping would might be more inefficient than eg devision, if possible at allö.

Comment: and whats the problem using div/mod?

Comment: Could you give an example using `div/mod`? Cause that's actually the problem: I don't know how to solve this without loops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, of course it's possible. Since you didn't give any particular implementation, I'll just put the numbers in an array. This is just a demonstration, of course. Assume NUM_OF_PERSONS is the number of persons in your array, and NUM_TO_DISTRIBUTE is the number you want to distribute. In your example, 8.

```
int persons[] = new int[NUM_OF_PERSONS];

int basicRation = NUM_TO_DISTRIBUTE / NUM_OF_PERSONS;
int peopleGettingExtra = NUM_TO_DISTRIBUTE % NUM_OF_PERSONS;

for ( int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_PERSONS; i ++ ) {
    persons[i] = basicRation + ( i < peopleGettingExtra ? 1 : 0 );
}
```

Test case 1: 9 to give, 3 people. The base ration is 3. The number of people getting extra is zero. In the loop, since no `i` will be less than 0, everybody will get `basicRation + 0` which means 3.

Test case 2: 8 to give, 3 people. The base ration is 2. The number of people getting extra is 2. In the loop, people with indexes 0 and 1 will get 2 + 1, and the last person gets 2 + 0.

Answer (score 2):

```
distributed = 0;
int howManyForEach = (int)(i/persons.size())

for(int p : person){
   p = howManyForEach ;
}
distrubuted = howManyForEach * persons.size();
while (distributed < i) {
    for (int p : persons) {
        p++;
        distributed++;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is only for the left over. For example 8/3 = 2. Put every person 2. 2*3 = 6. 8-6 =2(leftover). Now you will loop to distrubute these 2.

Answer (score 2):

The following code will run for **i=8 5 times**, **i=10 4 times**, **as i increase , number of time loop executed is proportionately less**

```
        int i = 10;

        int[] arr = new int[3] { 0, 0, 0 };

        int BaseVal = i / (arr.Length);
        int Remainder = i - (BaseVal * arr.Length);

        for (int x = 0; x < arr.Length  ;x++)
        {
            arr[x] = BaseVal;
        }
        for (int y = 0; y < Remainder; y++)
        {
            arr[y] = arr[y] + 1;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

from the problem it is clear, that the maximal difference between any person is `1`.

Just use `#persons / i = base value for every person`

and `#persons % i = # top persons with +1 value`

**Example**

```
i = 5 , persons = 3: 
baseValue = 1
#topPersons = 2 

=> 2 2 1
```